# sqlite many opens one fail

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have sqlite database in iPhone app and there I store questions.
I get one question, user answers YES or NO, result is showing on second viewController and when second viewController is closing I get another question.

Everything works perfectly and suddenly after 30-40 questions, program cannot open database.
if(sqlite3_open([DBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) - it fails.

Any answers?

This function:

// get Question from Database

```
- (void)getQuestion:(int)getQ
{
    NSLog(@"getQuestion Started");

    sqlite3 *database;

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement = NULL;

    if(sqlite3_open([DBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"sqlite opened");

        const char *sql = "Select QuestionID, Question from cQuestions WHERE ExerciseLinID = ? ORDER BY QuestionID LIMIT ?, 1";

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating detail view statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        int curExID = [[listOfExID objectAtIndex:ExSel] integerValue];
        sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 1, curExID);
        sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 2, getQ);

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(compiledStatement))
        {
            NSLog(@"Got one record");

            selectedQues = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);

            NSLog(@"selectedQues = %i", selectedQues);

            const char *QuNam = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);

            if(QuNam == nil)
                NSLog(@"!!! No data found.");
            else
            {
                if( iWhat == YES )
                    _labQuestion.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:QuNam encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                else
                    _labQuestionPad.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:QuNam encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"!!! Open error. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        NSLog(@"!!! Open error. %d", sqlite3_errcode(database));
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: Check the error using `sqlite3_errmsg`.

Comment: This is an error: Open error. unable to open database file

Comment: Are you *closing* the DB after you use it?  What does sqlite3_errmsg report??

Comment: And what is the failing return code?

Comment: My guess is that you're not closing the DB file and you run out of available file opens for the process.  (Check the return code from the close.)

Comment: (And, as others have indicated, it's not necessary to open the DB each time -- you can open it once and leave it open.)

Answer (score 1):

Add some NSLog to understand which is the error.

```
if(sqlite3_open([DBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    // Your Code
}
else {
    NSLog(@"sqlite3_open failed. Error:%d. %s", sqlite3_errcode(database), sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

One potential problem is the fact that you aren't closing your database, are you closing it?

```
sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: I'm closing database, it works 40 times and then fails.

Comment: There is nothing particular wrong in the posted code. Likely we need more code to understand the problem (are you doing something related to db in a backround thread?) However, one way to solve the problem could be to re-design your code to use only 1 open and 1 close, also if there is nothing wrong about opening\closing the db several times.

Comment: Again, I don't see nothing bad on the updated code, I would recommend to NSLog also `[DBPath UTF8String]`, just to be sure that when the open fails, the path is the expected path.